# Pane always on top - JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

My stage have as node, a boderpane with 2 childrens, one on top, one on bottom (like graphics for a game, on top big screen and on bottom the menu).

The idea is that the ''menu'' must be always on top.

Lets say screen size will be 500x400, top children will be 800x400 and bottom children will be 100x400.

I want that for user to be visible half-top side of topchildren and the bottom children.

I hope what I wrote is understandable.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some of your code to help others understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your concern.

I found answer.

I did not used borderpane as node for scene, but I used a simple pane.

I put both big gridpane and menu pane in same initial pane and i used

menuPane.relocate(0,360);

I also added a colored rectangle on the same coordonates but I assured to add menuPane as childern to initial pane, last one, to be in top of all.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to have a little tour on how this site works by navigating to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

To achieve the gui design you are looking for, you may want to play with other built-in layout panes of JavaFX. My first suggestion is to use

[pseudo code]

```
<VBox>
    <ScrollPane VBox.Vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <Big screen pane/>
    </ScrollPane>
    <Menu pane/>
</VBox>
```

Second suggestion is to use `AnchorPane` where the "Menu pane" always snaps to bottom border of the stage.